# C++ restrictive template friend function in template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Consider the code below:

```
// no forward declarations
//
// template<typename T>
// class A;
// 
// template<typename T>
// void swap(A<T>& lhs, A<T>& rhs);

template<typename T>
class A {
    int m_i;
public:
//  template<typename T1>
//  friend void swap<T1>(A<T1>& lhs, A<T1>& rhs);  // all instantiations of swap() 
                                                   // are friends: not restrictive

//  friend void swap<>(A<T>& lhs, A<T>& rhs);  // restrictive: only T instantiation 
                                               // is a friend, but it requires 
                                               // forward declaration

    friend void swap<>(A& lhs, A& rhs);  // note absence of brackets in arguments: 
                                         // restrictive as above, but no forward 
                                         // declaration required. Why not??

    A(int i = 0) : m_i{i} { }
};

template<typename T>
void swap(A<T>& lhs, A<T>& rhs) {
    A<double> cA;
//  cA.m_i = 0;    // compile-time error: swap<int> instantiation 
                   // is NOT a friend of A<double>
    //...
} 

int main() {
    A<int> cA1, cA2;    // A<int> instantiation
    swap(cA1, cA2);        
    return 0;
}
```

Code above compiles.

In class A, `friend void swap<>(A<T>& lhs, A<T>& rhs)` which requires a forward declatation seems to behave the same way as `friend void swap<>(A& lhs, A& rhs)` **without** the need for a forward declaration.

Can anyone explain, is there a difference between the two except that one requires a forward declaration, and the other does not? In what ways are they different to that effect?

Comment: What compiler? Clang [doesn't compile](http://rextester.com/TSF55281).

Comment: @songyuanyao : I'm using gcc 4.9.2, but It didn't compile at the link you've provided. I does compile with gcc 4.9.2, though. Are we writing it off as a compiler issue?

Comment: It might be a compiler bug which have been fixed at the latest version, I'm not sure. Anyway, the 3rd friend declaration is same as the 2nd one, so it still need the forward declaration of the function template.